# Storage of facebook user id

Tags: sql, facebook, identifier

Is there a maximum value to the id of a facebook user ?

I was using an SQL integer to store the value but it's not enough as I've encountered an id with 15 digits.

I'm guessing there is none (would be logical...) and that the equivalent of a big integer is being used ? So should I just switch to varchar(255) ?

Comment: I don't think Facebook have any plans on capping number of users, so you probably just have to plan for the future :)

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), a user's ID is a string (which may happen to contain only characters in the 0...9 range), not a number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Facebook once recommended that you store your `user_id` values as strings (can't find the reference anywhere now). [The documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) also says that the `user_id` value is a string.

In my experience, the `user_id` can be a `bigint(20)` value but I think it's a good idea to store it as a string to try prevent any possible future changes from messing with my applications. In any case, no numerical operations are really needed on the actual `user_id`; It's just a unique identifier. Make sure you use it as an index in your database's users table so that there will be no chance of duplicate user_ids.

Comment: @ida - in order to future proof your implementation, I would pretty much give the maximum that you feel your database can handle. Today the longest FBID I know is 15 characters, but with the growth of the system, this number could very soon reach 16..then 17... Rather go with a really really high number so that your system won't break sometime in the future.

Answer (score 3):

From [Java Practices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=716DB789603D5FB3C9009670F3B94129?Id=192), it's a good idea to store the facebook user ID in a string for the reasons mentioned in that tip. You could define an index on this field for faster filtering and I guess you are not going to perform any numeric-type queries on these user IDs.

Comment: It really is a language independent "good practice". People integrate with Facebook in many ways and with many languages. The `user_id` return by Facebook is constant in all cases.

Comment: Right, complete agree with that!

Comment: I happen to be a fan of Java Practices so this is a cool answer. I also agree with this is a good all-round practice :)